# MongoDB OR query in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

What is the correct code to compare username and experience using OR?

```
$regex = new MongoRegex("/".$name."*/i");
$regex2 = new MongoRegex("/".$comm."*/i");

$where = array('$in' => array('username' => array($regex),'experience' => array($regex2)));
$cursor = $collection->find($where)->limit($limit)->skip($skip);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want with an $in operator in the context of two regular expressions? Makes zero sense....look at the $or operator instead.